# Is maxPolygonVertices in Farseer physics engine only 8?

Tags: textures, polygon, physics, monogame, farseer

I use Farseer Physics Engine for pump simulation. In there Example, 
they always use texture2d format. But that pump shape is given just Point(x,y) Array.

I want to make polygon or texture2d from that point array.

PolygonTools.CreatePolygon method need int[] and width, not point[].

I don`t know how to make polygon by int[] and width.

please help.

I tried this way to solve above problem.

```
        Common.Vertices testVertices = new Common.Vertices(testVector);
        testBody = BodyFactory.CreatePolygon(World, testVertices, 1f);
        testBody.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

        SetUserAgent(testBody, 100f, 100f);
        testSprite = new Sprite(ScreenManager.Assets.TextureFromVertices(testVertices, MaterialType.Squares, Color.YellowGreen, 1f));
        _polygonTexture = testSprite.Texture;
```

testVector is my point array.
And I got Texture from point array by that way.

But... BodyFactory.CreatePolygon method support only 8 Vertices.
My Point are more than 8. 10000 or 100000. over..

I want to find another way to make Texture2D from my point[].

OR.. modify above Code to apply more than 8 points..please.

I am very appreciative of your help.

Thank you.